# Moment failing on some dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

Here are my dates, to me there is no different whatsoever. Yet moment can't handle them all:

```
console.info(details.date);
console.info(moment(details.date).format());
console.info('________________________________________');
result.date = moment(details.date, "DD-MM-YYYY H:m").format();

//Console
________________________________________
16/10/10 15:00
Invalid date
________________________________________
09/10/10 15:00
2010-09-10T15:00:00+01:00
```

How can I make my dates safe.

Comment: Is moment parsing it as mm/dd/yy (American style), because than 16/10/10 is an invalid date.

Comment: arghh... Who the hell uses american dates!! urgh! ;) That may well be it :)

Comment: Ummm from the documentation "By default, Moment.js comes with English locale strings."

Comment: English (United States) is what's highlighted on the main page. :) We do technically still speak a language called "English" here in the States.

Comment: haha, true enough. However its miss leading, they should be more spesific as you speak "english" but you don't use our dates

Comment: If you'd like add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: "English locale" refers to somewhere in England, whereas the English language is spoken in many locales. The use of "locale" to refer to preferences that have nothing to do with location illustrate that a much better term would have been "preference". But it doesn't sound so hip. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Moment is using the American Date convention, despite it not being documented in there [`moment(string)` interface](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

A simple example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnichols/qf37j7sn/)

Comment: It is documented: "*[moment] first check[s] if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, then fall back to new Date(string) if a known format is not found*" tells you that for the format in the OP, *moment* falls back to the browser's parser.

Comment: Fair, I assumed the browser was set to his locale, and would parse what he wrote. I guess Date.parse() is more the culprit then.

Comment: Browser parsers don't take any notice of regional settings for parsing date strings (some ignore them for *toLocaleString* too). If a user in Iceland is browsing a page on a web site hosted in Singapore with language set to Malaysian, what regional setting should be used to parse date strings?

Comment: Fair, again. I assumed Date.parse inverted Date.toLocaleString() or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [*moment(string)*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), if a format is not provided when parsing a string it will first try to match one of the ISO 8601 formats specified in ECMA-262. Failing that, it will simply pass the string to `new Date(string)`, which is the same as using *Date.parse*.

So the result is entirely implementation dependent. However, most browsers will treat nn/nn/nn as a US style date with two digit year, i.e. mm/dd/yy. But that is not guaranteed and may change from browser to browser.

The fix is to always pass the format when parsing strings.

In the second example, the format specified doesn't match the string supplied. It seems it falls back to *Date.parse* in this case also.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format string uses hyphons ("-") and actual date uses slashes ("/"), so Moment.Js is unable to parse it. Works fine in following example

```js
$("body").text(moment("16/10/10 15:00", "DD/MM/YY H:m").format())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```